# VB.NET - How do you read a value from another thread

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to read a value from a listview that is on the ui thread from another thread. I know how to set a value using:

`Invoke(Sub() Me.lv.Items.add("data"))`

But I need to retrieve a value from a listview and am not sure how. Here is what I  have so far:

`dim selectedItem = Invoke(Sub() Me.lv.Items(x).Text)`

I get an error that I need to assign the value to something, but not sure how to do that when I use invoke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dim selectedItem = CStr(Invoke(New Func(Of String)(Function() Me.lv.Items(x).Text)))
```

Comment: @Enigmativity, true. I added the cast.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
    Dim selectedItem As String
    Invoke(Sub()
               selectedItem = Me.lv.Items(x).Text
           End Sub)
```